# Як перекласти «Pluggable Transports» і де взагалі живуть перекладачі Tor та подібного ПЗ

Tags: переклад, from-english, неологізми, software

Pluggable — вставний, гаразд.
Transport, відповідно — транспорт.

> [Pluggable Transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports) help you bypass censorship against Tor. Pluggable Transports  transform the Tor traffic flow between the client and the bridge.

Я видозмінила словосполучення до «вставний транспорт**ер**», бо значення слова «транспорт» не як збірного поняття, а як одиниці, на мою думку, відходить в минуле, тоді як -ер прямо сигналізує про те, що це одиниця, яка виконує роботу.

Тепер переді мною стоїть друга половина питання, бо хочеться спитати у власне інших перекладачів продуктів Tor та іншого вільноперекладуваного ПЗ, чи нормальна така логіка. Transifex, де [перекладається](https://www.transifex.com/otf/torproject) Tor Project, спілкуванню між перекладачами мало сприяє, то може десь є чатоподібне «місце зустрічі»?

Comment: Мені здається, «вставний» тут не дуже пасує. В контексті физичного пристрою: так, «pluggable» — «вставний». Але англійське «pluggable» значно легше розширює значення (набуває переносних значень) за українське «вставний». В даному випадку я сказав би, що «pluggable» — це «той, що його можна підключити (підімкнути, приєднати, залучити, застосувати)». Шкода, що в українській мові не можна це сказати одним словом (не завжди існують дієприкметники), але «вставний» (особливо поряд з «транспорт(ом)») — це, по-моєму, не зовсім те.

Comment: От [e2u](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=pluggable) пропонує «знімний», «змінний» — хоча це не завжди прийнятні варіанти.

Comment: Нмд, наскільки я в'їхала в тему, _вставний_ тут якраз добре відповідає суті. Між користувачем і мережею Тор _вставляється_ щось на зразок прокладки (і важливо, що вона там може бути, а не те, що її можна зняти чи замінити). І через неї транспортуються / вона _транпортує_ дані.

Comment: Я знаю, що деякі перекладачі подібного ПЗ живуть на [linux.org.ua](http://linux.org.ua/). Також є поштова розсилка [команди українських перекладачів](http://translationproject.org/team/uk.html) Translation Project, [localize.org.ua](http://localize.org.ua/), [розділ](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showforum=8) на forum.slovnyk.ua й  інші.

Comment: Можливо, але мені все ж здається, що «pluggable» в даному контексті означає, «ті [транспорти], що їх можна підключити», а не те, що вони вставляються між користувачем і мережею Tor. (Те, що вони вставляються *між користувачем і мережею Tor* — в даному випадку просто співпадіння (точніше, це безпосередній зміст слова «transport», а не «pluggable»); а от те, що їх можна (і дуже легко) опціонально підключати і не підключати (і вони різні) — це вже «pluggable».) Але можу помилятися.

Comment: @Sasha, можете, бдлск, винести сайти і розсилки в окрему відповідь?

Answer (score 5):

Мовно-технічний портал MicroSoft:

1. [**Transport:**](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=Transport&langID=uk-ua) [транспорт](http://sum.in.ua/s/transport) без [-ер](http://sum.in.ua/s/transporter); [транспортування](http://sum.in.ua/s/transportuvannja);
2. [**Pluggable:**](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=Pluggable&langID=uk-ua) [модуль](http://sum.in.ua/s/modulj)·[ний](http://sum.in.ua/s/moduljnyj); [під](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#.D0.94.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.96_.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F)ʼ[єдн](http://sum.in.ua/s/jednaty)уваний;

---

**Щодо осідків перекладачів ПЗ** нічого сказати не можу, але осідок перекладачів ігор й щось подібне можна знайти на [Діскорді.](https://discord.gg/gaj8vVr)